# Time Delay for IPTV on Wowza Server

Tags: scripting, wowza

Can you help me scripting for time Delay on wowza server?
We need to stream live content and delayed content to suite the needs of the users on a different time zones.

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific requirements, you can take a look at the [DVR](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?300) or [Recording](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?123-LiveStreamRecord-Module-for-recording-a-live-stream-on-demand&page=11) modules.  Also, you way want to ask your question at http://www.wowza.com/forums/.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at gstreamill, with gstreamill you can access live as following:

```
.../dvr/name/playlist.m3u8?offset=-xxxx
```

`offset=-xxxx` means `xxxx` seconds before just now